# Apache Tika not properly extracting text from PDF for Indian languages

Tags: apache-tika

I tried to extract text from PDF, it is working fine for English but not for Indian languages like Hindi, Tamil, Malayalam etc... See the sample below, all the bold text in the extracted content is not correct. Does Tika work with non English languages?

**Original Text :**

மக்களுக்குப் புத்தாண்டு பரிசாக, எல்இடி டிவி, சினிமா டிக்கெட், கம்ப்யூட்டர் மானிட்டர், மாற்றுத்திறனாளிகளுக்கான உதிரிப்பாகங்கள் உள்ளிட்ட 23 வகை பொருட்கள், சேவைகளின் குறைக்கப்பட்ட ஜிஎஸ்டி வரி இன்று முதல் அமலுக்கு வந்தது.

**Extracted Text :**

**மக்களக்கப் பத்தாண்ட** பரிசாக,  **எல்இடடவ**,  சனிமா **டக்ககட,்  கம்ப்யட்டர்** மானிட்டர,்

**மாற்றத்தறனாளிகளக்கானஉதரிப்பாகங்கள்** உள்ளிட்ட 23
 **வகககபாரடக்ள்,  சசகவகளின்**

**ககறக்கப்படட் ஜஎஸ்ட** வரி **இன்றமதல் அமலக்கவந்தத**.

**UPDATE:**

If I convert the PDF to JPG and use **TesseractOCRParser** and mention the language as **Tamil** then it works lot better than the **PDFParser**

Comment: If you select the text in Acrobat and cut-n-paste it out to something like notepad, do you get the right text, or basically the same that Tika gets?

Comment: @Gagravarr Just checked, copy paste also not working properly, same as Tika

Comment: Right, your problem is with whatever produced the PDF then. It has almost certainly done some bad OCR, and put that text behind the image of the scan. Your only option is to tell Apache Tika to re-OCR it, and ignore the text in the PDF

Comment: @Gagravarr I am now doing ocr_only strategy and it works lot better, thanks